# Safety check - Is this Amazon PV combiner box labeled wrong? 15A Vs 32A - 500V vs 1000V

Tags: dc, fuses, solar-energy, circuit-breaker

I'm currently working on a solar circuit. I wanted to protect my internal systems from my panels in the event of a surge. I purchased a PV combiner box from Amazon - [link to product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09RH46XL5).

It claims to be a four-string box with 15A DC fuses and a 500V 63A DC circuit breaker.

When the product arrived, the fuses are labeled 1000v DC 32A and the circuit breaker seems to be labeled 500V 6000A.

Am I missing something or has someone dangerously mislabeled this box "VEVOR PV Combiner Box, 4 String with 15A Rated Current Fuse, 63A Circuit Breaker, Lightning Arreste Connector for On/Off Grid Solar Panel System, IP65"?

[image]

Comment: 32A is the rating on the fuse holder, above that you'd destroy the whole kit (not just the replaceable fuse).  The current limit depends on what fuse is installed into the fuse holder.

Comment: I buy stuff like that from other places... Like stores that sell electrical gear as a business and they know how it works.

Comment: 6000A is probably the maximum allowable fault current. I think C63 means it's a 63-amp breaker and the C is how fast it trips? Not actually sure though.

Comment: @BenVoigt, So that is just a holder? I was thinking it's one whole fuse shaped similar to a breaker.

Comment: Yes, it's a fuseholder, the fuse is inside and not visible unless you open the access door.  The part numbers are clearly visible in your photo and easy to search for.  See https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/CFPV-32-2P-Solar-PV-Protection_62025055968.html   Fuses always have to be socketed, unlike circuit breakers which can be reset, a tripped fuse has to be removed and replaced, and the socket makes that possible without having to rewire.

Comment: So open your fuseholders, check that there actually are fuses in the sockets, remove and inspect them to see if those have the rating you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 6000A rating on the circuit breaker is the maximum surge current that it is guaranteed to safely interrupt.  The voltage ratings are the maximum allowable voltage, and should be higher than the actual voltage you're using in your system.  And as @Ben Voigt already mentioned, the 32A rating on the fuseholder is for the fuseholder itself, the installed fuse can be anything below that.